# What is sequential composition?

Tags: language-agnostic

In [this video (6:08)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-h5qpXO3isM&t=6m8s), the speaker mentions the phrase

> There is a style of programming called Sequential Composition which means that the programmers can work on really narrow functionality and have the pieces go together to enable a very wide range of capability

A quick google search gave me [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_calculus) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137815/writing-multiple-functions-in-sml-sequential-composition) but to my naive eyes, they seem like normal sequential programming

Would someone kindly explain what exactly is this Sequential Composition he is referring to?  And how does it enable the behaviour he mentioned?

Comment: Just watched that exact video and boom - ended up on Stack. Thanks for asking!

Comment: Just watched that exact video and boom - ended up on Stack. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm pretty sure they're talking about control systems not programming languages. Have a look at [Sequential Composition of Dynamically Dexterous Robot Behaviors](https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/67990/10.1177_02783649922066385.pdf?sequence=2). This might give you a clue on what else to search on. There is an [abstract here that might help as well](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7298427/).